# What's wrong with this code? (for checking palindrones)

Tags: javascript

I think I need to create a new variable but when ever I do so it acts a function.

```
function palindrome(str) {
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
str = str.split("");
if (str == str.reverse()) {
return(true);

}

else if(str != str.reverse()) {
return (false);
}
return str;
}



palindrome("eye");
```

Comment: "Acts like a function"? Huh? Also, `return` is not a function, those parentheses are useless. You could just shorten it to `return str === str.reverse()`.

Comment: After you split str and compare it to str.reverse, you are trying to compare two arrays using `==`.  That won't work.  One way around that is to use the `.join('')` method to turn them both back into strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function palindrome(str){
    str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").split("");
    return str.join('') == str.reverse().join('');
}
```